# combineLatest with arrays of observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

How would one go about using `combineLatest` with two or more arrays of observables?

```js
const array1 = [of(1), of(2)];
const array2 = [of(3), of(4)];

combineLatest(array1, array2)
  .subscribe(([array1, array2]) => {
    console.log(
      `array1[0]: ${array1[0]}
      array1[1]: ${array1[1]}
      array2[0]: ${array2[0]}
      array2[1]: ${array2[1]}`
    );
  });
```

I have a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cnzvlo?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `combineLatest` function expects an array of `Observable`(s), not an array of array of `Observable`.

So what do you have to do is:

- Convert each array of `Observable`, to an `Observable`, by combining the inner `Observable`(s) of each one of them using `concat` function.
- Then convert the result of each one to an array using `toArray` operator.

You can do something like the following:

```js
import { combineLatest, of, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const array1 = [of(1), of(2)];
const array2 = [of(3), of(4)];

combineLatest([
  concat(...array1).pipe(toArray()),
  concat(...array2).pipe(toArray()),
]).subscribe(([array1, array2]) => {
  console.log(
    `array1[0]: ${array1[0]}
      array1[1]: ${array1[1]}
      array2[0]: ${array2[0]}
      array2[1]: ${array2[1]}`
  );
});
```

And here is the working version of your StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3imea6?file=index.ts